# how to select oldest record of each group in a dataframe? using python

Tags: python, select, grouping, data-cleaning

As an example, a dataframe that looks like this:

```
         date  price ticker  volume
0   2018-01-01  1.323     AI    2000
1   2018-01-02  1.525     AI    1500
2   2018-01-03  1.045     AI     500
3   2018-01-04  1.845     AI     600
4   2018-01-05  1.045     AI     500
5   2018-01-02  1.446    BOC     550
6   2018-01-03  2.110    BOC    3201
7   2018-01-04  2.150    BOC    5200
8   2018-01-05  2.810    BOC    1980
9   2018-01-03  5.199    CAT    2000
10  2018-01-06  4.980    CAT     450
11  2018-01-07  4.990    CAT    3000
```

I am going to ask a very basic question, please bear with me
how can choose the first two ticker that has oldest date, to have a dataframe like below

```
         date  price ticker  volume
0   2018-01-01  1.323     AI    2000
1   2018-01-02  1.525     AI    1500
5   2018-01-01  1.446    BOC     550
6   2018-01-02  2.110    BOC    3201
9   2018-01-01  5.199    CAT    2000
10  2018-01-02  4.980    CAT     450
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Pandas, you can use `groupby` command to group values. Also, by using `head` command with `groupby` command, you can select first two values in the group. So, in your case, to group first two ticker, the command will be:

```
df.sort_values('date').groupby('ticker').head(2)
```